# How to wait the page to test is loaded in non angular site?

Tags: protractor, wait

I've tried this:

```
 browser.wait(function () {
        return browser.executeScript('return document.readyState==="complete" &&' +
            ' jQuery !== undefined && jQuery.active==0;').then(function (text) {
                return text === true;
            });
    }, 30000);
```

If `jQuery.active==0` then page is completely loaded. This should work for sites with JQuery and non angular pages.

However, I have many problems of instability to test for non angular sites.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

By default protractor waits until the page is loaded completely. If you are facing any error then it is because protractor is waiting for the default time to be completed, that you have specified in your conf.js file to wait until page loads. Change the value to wait a for longer time if you think your app is slow -

```
// How long to wait for a page to load.
getPageTimeout: 10000, //Increase this time to whatever you think is better
```

You can also increase the `defaultTimeoutInterval` to make protractor wait a little longer before the test fails -

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},
```

If you want to wait for any particular element, then you can do so by using `wait()` function. Probably waiting for last element to load is the best way to test it. Here's how -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var lastElement = element(LOCATOR_OF_LAST_ELEMENT);
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(lastElement), 10000).then(function(){ //Alternatively change the visibilityOf to presenceOf to check for the element's presence only
    //Perform operation on the last element
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: protractor waits until the page is loaded completely in angular sites. When you test non angular sites, and set   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true, protractor doesn't wait.

Comment: @winlinuz protractor is a wrapper over selenium and selenium does wait until page completes rendering the data to the client browser. Are you still getting any error after using the above methods? Also if you ajax content then protractor wouldnt know about it. In that case you can wait for the element.

Comment: I wanted say how to wait DOM elements are loaded. I have issues to perform actions such as click, etc. because the element is not loaded and protractor doesn't find.

Comment: @winlinuz are you dynamically creating/loading the content in? Girish is right in that Selenium should wait until page load before looking up elements.

Comment: @Nick Tomlin yes, sometimes we have ajax requests that are loaded in grid after the rest of DOM elements are presents.

Comment: @winlinuz you can still wait until the ajax elements are loaded using `wait()` function and provide the element that you want to wait for. Have you tried using it? What error do you get when you use that function?

Answer (score 2):

I use [ExpectedConditions](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) to wait for, and verify page loads. I [walk through it a bit on my site](http://qualityshepherd.com/2015/08/protractor-navigating-pages-without-angular/), and [example code on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example). Here's the gist...

**Base Page:** (gets extended by all page objects)

```
// wait for & verify correct page is loaded
this.at = function() {
    var that = this;
    return browser.wait(function() {
        // call the page's pageLoaded method
        return that.pageLoaded();
    }, 5000);
};

// navigate to a page 
this.to = function() {
    browser.get(this.url, 5000);
    // wait and verify we're on the expected page
    return this.at();
};
...
```

**Page Object:**

```
var QsHomePage = function() {
    this.url = 'http://qualityshepherd.com';

    // pageLoaded uses Expected Conditions `and()`, that allows us to use
    // any number of functions to wait for, and test we're on a given page
    this.pageLoaded = this.and(
        this.hasText($('h1.site-title'), 'Quality Shepherd')
    ...

};
QsHomePage.prototype = basePage; // extend basePage
module.exports = new QsHomePage();
```

The page object may contain a url (if direct access is possible), and a pageLoaded property that returns the ExepectedCondition function that we use to prove the page is loaded (and the right page).

**Usage:**

```
describe('Quality Shepherd blog', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
       // go to page
       qsHomePage.to();
    });

    it('home link should navigate home', function() {
        qsHomePage.homeLink.click();

        // wait and verify we're on expected page
        expect(qsHomePage.at()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Calling `at()` calls the ExpectedCondidion (which can be be an `and()` or an `or()`, etc...).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Base Page is similar to a Page Object usage? We put module.exports?

Comment: Yeah, basePage is extended by all pages; i.e. all methods are available in all pages. I have a full, working example on GitHub: https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example